# How to answer this limit question

Tags: real-analysis

Evaluate the limit as n tends to infinity of:
$(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$.

Heres what I tried:
$(n^\frac{1}{n}(1-{n^{-\frac{1}{n}}})^n = n(1-{n^{-\frac{1}{n}}})^n$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I see. I dont see how they derived it though, is it a known fact and thus i just have to memorise it or can you derive it from just seeing the problem

Comment: the searched Limit is zero

Comment: In the answer to a similar question in another post it says that  $n^\frac{1}{n}$ is between 0 and 0.5 i dont get how they got the 0.5 can someone explain please

Comment: It's not $n^{1/n}$ that's between 0 and 0.5, it's the whole expression $n^{1/n}-1$. And that's because $n^{1/n} \to 1$, so we can make $^{1/n}<1+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ by making $n$ large enough. In particular (with $\epsilon=1/2$) it's true that $n^{1/n}<3/2$ for all large enough $n$.

Answer (score 0):

write your Limit in the form $$e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(n^{1/n}-1)}{\frac{1}{n}}}$$